# CakePHP conditional find

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, models, model-associations

I'm writing a simple Blog application. I am dealing with two models, `BlogPost` and `BlogCategory`.

They both have a HABTM relationship to each other using a separate table.

I have written a function in the BlogPost model to load all the posts from a certain category, but it keeps producing a database error.

```
public function getRecentFromCategory($category, $offset, $limit){
     return $this->find('all', array(
         'order' => 'BlogPost.date desc',
         'offset' => $offset,
         'limit' => $limit,
         'conditions' => array('BlogCategory.id' => $category)
     ));
 }
```

Why can't I make a conditional based on the associated categories?

Comment: It shows the query but it clearly isn't actually linking to BlogCategory in the query. It just suddenly has a WHERE BlogCategory.id=etc, but it never sets up the relationship.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/328876 | http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Comment: I just feel like something as simple as searching within a related model should be simpler than that. Is that really the only way?

Comment: AFAIK this is unfortunately the only way if you want to use the Cake syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a `belongsTo` relationship between your models, meaning your BlogPosts can belong to a BlogCategory.

Assuming your BlogPost has a 'blog_category_id' field, in your BlogPost model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'BlogCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'BlogCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'blog_category_id'
    )
);
```

Then your find should be able to filter based on category in the way you want.

Comment: In a `HABTM` relationship the foreign keys are in the join table, so creating a `belongsTo` relationship is not possible.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the HABTM part of his post. Same thing though, you would use a syntax such as this (as described on the book link you posted in the OP comments), and set up your join table.